# How to update items in array for inverted flatlist

Tags: react-native

Here is my code:

```
 response.data.data.map((item, index) => {
                console.log('response',item);
                const itemIndex = dataList.findIndex(v => v.dt3 === item.dt3);
                if (itemIndex > -1) {
                  //update quantity in list if same item is selected more than one time
                  const value = {
                    ds: item.ds,
                    bl: item.bl,
                    mty: item.od_auto.Mty,
                    name: item.customer_name_auto,
                  };
                  dataList.push(value);
                } else {
                  const value = {
                    ds: item.ds,
                    bl: item.bl,
                    mty: item.od_auto.Mty,
                    name: item.customer_name_auto,
                  };
                  dataList.push(item.dt3);
                  for(let i = 0; i<dataList.length; i++){
                    dataList[i] = value;
                  }             
                }
              });
```

Expected output:

```
 const DATA = [
    {
    title: '4th April, 2020',
    data: [
      {
    ds: item.ds,
                    bl: item.bl,
                    mty: item.od_auto.Mty,
                    name: item.customer_name_auto,
    },{
    ds: item.ds,
                    bl: item.bl,
                    mty: item.od_auto.Mty,
                    name: item.customer_name_auto,
    }
     ],
    },
    {
    title: '3rd April, 2020',
    data: [
    {
    ds: item.ds,
                    bl: item.bl,
                    mty: item.od_auto.Mty,
                    name: item.customer_name_auto,
    },{
    ds: item.ds,
                    bl: item.bl,
                    mty: item.od_auto.Mty,
                    name: item.customer_name_auto,
    }
     ],
    },
    {
    title: '2nd April, 2020',
    data: [
    {
    ds: item.ds,
                    bl: item.bl,
                    mty: item.od_auto.Mty,
                    name: item.customer_name_auto,
    },{
    ds: item.ds,
                    bl: item.bl,
                    mty: item.od_auto.Mty,
                    name: item.customer_name_auto,
    }
     ],
    },
    {
    title: '1st April, 2020',
    data: [
     {
    ds: item.ds,
                    bl: item.bl,
                    mty: item.od_auto.Mty,
                    name: item.customer_name_auto,
    },{
    ds: item.ds,
                    bl: item.bl,
                    mty: item.od_auto.Mty,
                    name: item.customer_name_auto,
    }
     ],
    },
    ];
```

This is how my API response looks:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "aid": 188427,
            "s": 1,
            "dt": "19th Oct 2022",
            "dt3": "19-10-2022",
            "ds": "Proceeds",
            "cr": 172,
            "bk": "sdlsjkfhjdfhgf",
            "bkid": 1,
            "up": "",
            "od": {
                "Mty": "",
                "Mre": "",
                "Mct": "",
                "Mci": "",
                "Mdt": "",
                "Mdi": ""
            },
            "typ": "",
            "cnm": "",
            "tm": "19th Oct 2022 19:31",
            "bl": "224",
            "od_auto": {
                "Mty": "Services",
                "Mci": 77,
                "Mct": 2,
                "Mre": "",
                "Mdt": "",
                "Mdi": ""
            },
            "customer_name_auto": null
        },
        {
            "aid": 188426,
            "s": 2,
            "dt": "19th Oct 2022",
            "dt3": "19-10-2022",
            "ds": "cslkdjfhsjkdfhjshfjs",
            "cr": 1.01,
            "bk": "slkdjfhsjkdfhljdfh",
            "bkid": 397,
            "up": "",
            "od": {
                "Mty": "",
                "Mre": "",
                "Mct": "",
                "Mci": "",
                "Mdt": "",
                "Mdi": ""
            },
            "typ": "",
            "cnm": "",
            "tm": "19th Oct 2022 18:07",
            "bl": "2487.22",
            "od_auto": {
                "Mty": "djfdfhghgh",
                "Mci": 181,
                "Mct": 1,
                "Mre": "",
                "Mdt": "",
                "Mdi": ""
            },
            "customer_name_auto": "skdhfshdghsd"
        },
]}
```

I am fetching the response from API to create Inverted flatlist. In my response array I have date object for each item in the array. Now I want to group the items which has same date in an array. How can I arrange the array items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to group your array of objects based on the date attribute then you can use this function

```js
const data_array  = {
    "status": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "aid": 188427,
            "s": 1,
            "dt": "19th Oct 2022",
            "dt3": "19-10-2022",
            "ds": "Proceeds",
            "cr": 172,
            "bk": "sdlsjkfhjdfhgf",
            "bkid": 1,
            "up": "",
            "od": {
                "Mty": "",
                "Mre": "",
                "Mct": "",
                "Mci": "",
                "Mdt": "",
                "Mdi": ""
            },
            "typ": "",
            "cnm": "",
            "tm": "19th Oct 2022 19:31",
            "bl": "224",
            "od_auto": {
                "Mty": "Services",
                "Mci": 77,
                "Mct": 2,
                "Mre": "",
                "Mdt": "",
                "Mdi": ""
            },
            "customer_name_auto": null
        },
        {
            "aid": 188426,
            "s": 2,
            "dt": "19th Oct 2022",
            "dt3": "19-10-2022",
            "ds": "cslkdjfhsjkdfhjshfjs",
            "cr": 1.01,
            "bk": "slkdjfhsjkdfhljdfh",
            "bkid": 397,
            "up": "",
            "od": {
                "Mty": "",
                "Mre": "",
                "Mct": "",
                "Mci": "",
                "Mdt": "",
                "Mdi": ""
            },
            "typ": "",
            "cnm": "",
            "tm": "19th Oct 2022 18:07",
            "bl": "2487.22",
            "od_auto": {
                "Mty": "djfdfhghgh",
                "Mci": 181,
                "Mct": 1,
                "Mre": "",
                "Mdt": "",
                "Mdi": ""
            },
            "customer_name_auto": "skdhfshdghsd"
        },
]}


var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

console.log(groupBy(data_array.data, 'dt3'));
```

You can group your array with any object attribute:

```
let data_group_by_date = groupBy(data_array.data, 'dt3')
```

You can u section list data with the this code:

```
const sections_list_data = [];
Object.keys(data_group_by_date).map((item, i) => {
  sections.push({
    title: item,
    data: data_group_by_date[item],
  });
});
```

Comment: this code is not providing values from object od and od_auto

Comment: check this output it has all the values. or share your output

Comment: thank you its working.but i want to give a name for date param

Comment: i want exactly same like expected output in my above code

Comment: i got it its working perfectly thank you so much for your suggestion

Comment: if (response.data.status == 1) {
          let data = groupBy(response.data.data, 'dt3');
          const sections_list_data = [];
          Object.keys(data).map((item, i) => {
            sections_list_data.push({title: item, data: data[item]});
          });
          setDataList(sections_list_data);
          // console.log(sections_list_data,'list');
        }

Comment: this is my code

Comment: I am getting error

Comment: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {aid, s, dt, dt3, ds, cr, bk, bkid, up, od, typ, cnm, tm, bl, od_auto, customer_name_auto}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: this is the error

Comment: this is not error in the function. its is error with your code. i think u are displaying object in the Text  Filder. user obj.arrtrbue for each attribue of your object you want to dispaly.

Comment: i have fixed finally

Comment: but when i open the app list is aligned at the bottom of the page

Comment: now this is styling issue. justifyConent and alignItems search about these and flex

Comment: stickyDate: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: 10,
   },   this style i have applied for the view

Comment: <SectionList
     sections={dataList}
     inverted={true}
     keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
     renderItem={({ item }) => <ItemView item={item} />}
     renderSectionFooter={({ section: { title } }) => (
        <View style={styles.stickyDate}>
          <Text style={{color:Colors.blueText}}>{title}</Text>
         </View>
      )}
     /> here is the sectionlIst

Comment: check the second answer

Comment: i have removed inverted option now its working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Add this Modules> Modify it a little bit.

```
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  SectionList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import {RFValue} from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {hp, wp} from '../constants/scaling';
import {colors, fonts} from '../constants/theme';
import {titleCase} from '../functions/commonfunction';
import {textStyles} from '../styles/textStyles';
const Item = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: wp(90),
        height: hp(6),
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderBottomColor: colors.inputBgColor,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
      }}>
      <FontAwesome
        name={'map-marker'}
        style={{marginRight: wp(2)}}
        color={'#a1aac4'}
        size={wp(6)}
      />
      <Text
        numberOfLines={1}
        style={{
          ...textStyles.Label,
          textAlign: 'center',
          fontFamily: fonts.Medium,
        }}>
        {item.name}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const SectionListDropDown = ({
  isModalVisible,
  setIsModalVisible,
  setSelectedValue,
}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [suggestionsList, setSuggestionsList] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (search.trim().length > 2) {
      ur_api_call_here_and_other_logic (search);
    }
  }, [search]);

   const ur_api_call_here_and_other_logic = () => {
    }

  return (
    <Modal
      style={{
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        margin: 0,
      }}
      useNativeDriver={true}
      backdropColor={colors.primaryColor}
      backdropOpacity={1}
      hideModalContentWhileAnimating={true}
      backdropTransitionOutTiming={0}
      animationInTiming={500}
      animationOutTiming={500}
      isVisible={isModalVisible}
      onBackdropPress={setIsModalVisible}>
      <View style={styles.main_view}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: wp(90),
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
            //backgroundColor: colors.inputBgColor,
            height: hp(7),
            marginBottom: wp(2),
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={setIsModalVisible}>
            <Entypo name="cross" size={wp(7)} color={colors.textPrimaryColor} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text
            style={{
              ...textStyles.heading,
              marginLeft: wp(4),
              fontFamily: fonts.Bold,
            }}>
            Departure
          </Text>
        </View>
        <SectionList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          sections={suggestionsList}
          ListEmptyComponent={
            <Text
              style={{
                ...textStyles.Label,
                textAlign: 'center',
                fontFamily: fonts.Bold,
              }}>
              Please Enter a least three characters
            </Text>
          }
          scrollEventThrottle={500}
          ListHeaderComponent={
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                backgroundColor: colors.inputBgColor,
                height: hp(7),
                alignItems: 'center',
                flexDirection: 'row',
                paddingHorizontal: wp(5),
                borderRadius: wp(2),
                marginBottom: wp(2),
                width: wp(90),
              }}>
              <FontAwesome
                name={'circle-o'}
                style={{marginRight: wp(2)}}
                color={'#a1aac4'}
                size={wp(6)}
              />
              <TextInput
                value={search}
                onChangeText={text => setSearch(text)}
                placeholderTextColor={colors.secondaryTextColor}
                placeholder="Search here your destination"
                style={{
                  width: wp(72),
                  fontFamily: fonts.Medium,
                  includeFontPadding: false,
                  borderRadius: wp(2),
                  paddingHorizontal: wp(2),
                  backgroundColor: colors.inputBgColor,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  color: colors.textPrimaryColor,
                  fontSize: RFValue(14),
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  alignSelf: 'center',
                  height: hp(7),
                }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Item item={item} />}
          renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: colors.primaryColor,
                width: wp(90),
                height: hp(7),
                flexDirection: 'row',
                marginVertical: wp(2),
                borderRadius: wp(1),
                alignItems: 'center',
                paddingHorizontal: wp(2),
              }}>
              {title == 'hotels' ? (
                <FontAwesome
                  name={'hotel'}
                  style={{marginRight: wp(2)}}
                  color={'#fff'}
                  size={wp(6)}
                />
              ) : (
                <FontAwesome
                  name={'circle-o'}
                  style={{marginRight: wp(2)}}
                  color={'#fff'}
                  size={wp(6)}
                />
              )}
              <Text
                style={{
                  ...textStyles.heading,
                  fontFamily: fonts.Bold,
                  color: colors.white,
                }}>
                {titleCase(title)}
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
        {loading && (
          <View style={styles.loadingView}>
            <ActivityIndicator color={colors.textPrimaryColor} size={'large'} />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};
export default SectionListDropDown;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_view: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    //borderTopLeftRadius: wp(5),
    padding: wp(5),
    paddingVertical: wp(2),
    flex: 1,
    //borderTopRightRadius: wp(5),
  },
});
```